# running functions via import in python

Tags: python, function, python-import

I have the following scripts:

the first is `test1.py`

```
x = 1

def test():

    globx = x
    print(globx)
    globx += 1
    return globx

x = test()
```

and the second is `test2.py`

```
import test1

z=3
while z != 0:
    if __name__=='__main__':
        test1.test()
        z -= 1
    else: 
        pass
```

I'm using these to learn and play about with calling functions from other scripts, what I want is the output:

```
1
2
3
```

but I get:

```
1
2
2
2
```

when I replace the

```
    globx = x
    print(globx)
    globx += 1
    return globx

x = test()
```

in `test1.py` with

```
global x 
print(x) 
x += 1
```

I do get the desired outcome but apparently you shouldn't use global variables so it's a habit I'd like to break.

I have 2 questions.

1. Why do I get the wrong output and
2. Why are there 4 outputs when I use the `globx = x` version of `test1.py` instead of 3?

Answer (score 2):

**Why do I get the wrong output?**

When you import `test1` is runs for the first time, executing `test` for the first time and assigning it to `x`, printing `1` and incrementing `x`.

Then you execute `test` another 3 times inside `test2`, but without updating `x`, so `test` will set `globx` with `x`, print `x` and update `globx`, yet leaving `x` untouched (stuck on `2`).

**Why are there 4 outputs?**

You set `z` to `3`, then count to `0`. `z = 3, 2, 1, 0 OVER!`. So you execute for `z = 1..3`, resulting in 3 times **+** the time that executes inside `test1` itself, when loaded.

**How to fix?**

*On `test1.py`:*

Use global `x` for all actions. Don't run `test`:

```
x = 1

def test():
    global x
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

*On `test2.py`:*

Iterate 3 times with `range`. Your `else: pass` would trigger infinite loop if the module was run by another one:

```
import test1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(3):
        test1.test()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well but I was hoping to avoid using `global`

Comment: You could use generators, but that would be more complex. How else did you thought of keeping the current value without a global?

Comment: by using `return globx` and then setting `x = test()`

Comment: that would work only if you set `x` manually every time you call `test` (`test1.x = test1.test()`), and technically, `x` would still be a global.

Comment: Ahh I see. Would there be a way of sending `x` or any other variable say by using  `input()` or just setting it into `test1` from `test2`

Comment: see my last comment (`test1.x = test1.test()` instead of `test1.test()`).

Answer (score 0):

When you `import test1`, the whole script is executed. The function `test()` is called for the first time. It prints 1 and changes `x` to 2. Then you call `test1.test()` three times in the loop. `globx` is a local variable. It is printed three times (`2`) and changed three times to 3, but the changes are not saved.